# How to join two tables in SQL query without repetition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
User_Master (ID is Primary Key   identity)

ID      Name    Age      Gender
1       James   25       Male
2       John    30       Male

User_Image (User_Id is foreign key from User_Master)

ID     User_Id   Thumbnail
1         2       ABC.Jpeg
2         2       AB.jpeg
```

I need to get All fields from `User_Master` and one thumbnail name of that selected user  from `User_Image` table

Like this :

```
User_Id    Name         Age      Gender Thumbnail
1          James        25       Male   null
2          John         30       Male   ABC.Jpeg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way, assuming you want the image with the lowest id as there are obviously multiple options;

```
select 
    id, name, age, gender, thumbnail 
from (
    select
        rank() over (partition by m.id order by i.id asc) as rank,
        m.id,
        name, 
        age, 
        gender, 
        thumbnail
    from
        User_Master m left join User_Image i on (i.user_id = m.id)
) t where rank = 1
```

Comment: You should not use `RANK()` for this as it may give back multiple answers with same value. Use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother..God bless u :)
Its working now with ROW_NUMBER().